# WMI use to deploy MSI to multiple computers via text list

Tags: batch-file, windows-installer, wmi, wmic

I searched through stackoverflow and I find bits and pieces, but I'm stuck.
I have no access to our deployment tools. PowerShell is restricted. I have admin rights to all of the machines that I need to perform this task.

64-bit Windows 7 environment.

Code I've been trying to make work -

```
REM @ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
Set _computer=C:\Support\BatchTests\Chrome.txt
ECHO *********************************************************
ECHO.
ECHO Installing Chrome on %_computer%. Stand by...
ECHO.
ECHO *********************************************************
Xcopy "\\network\path\to\msi\googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi" "\\%_computer%\C$\Support\" /E /C /H /R /Y
wmic /node:%_computer% product call install true,"","\\%_computer%\C$\Support\googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi"
REM DEL /Q "\\%_computer%\C$\Support\googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi"
```

I initially tried using wmic by itself, but determined that the msi needs to be housed on the remote machine rather than network share.

I also tried using this code

```
    for /f %%i in (C:\Support\BatchTests\chrome.txt) DO (

    set pcname=%%i

    ECHO *********************************************************
    ECHO.
    ECHO Installing Chrome on %pcname%. Stand by...
    ECHO.
    ECHO *********************************************************
    Xcopy "\\Network\path\to\msi\googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi" "\\%pcname%\C$\Support\" /E /C /H /R /Y
    wmic /node:%pcname% product call install true,"","\\%pcname%\C$\Support\googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi"
    REM DEL /Q "\\%pcname%\C$\Support\googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi"
)
```

With the above code, it generally works, however, it does not pull the new "set variable" and holds onto the first defined variable (computer name).

The use of utilities is extremely limited, so please keep recommendations in the confines of vbs or batch file.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When using a text file containing the PC names for `WMIC /Node:` you should prefix the file name with **`@`**

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Compo. I tried using the wmic command directly, but there is an issue running the msi via network share. So the MSI must be copied to the remote computer and the install command to point to that file. Using the typical wmic /node:@C:\computers.txt doesn't work.

Comment: My comment was just a fix to your first code snippet, the second code snippet either requires the use of `!pcname!` with `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` or don't bother setting it and just use `%%i` in place of `%pcname%`.

Comment: Thank you Compo! It's working beautifully!